# How to display default and custom pager in bxslider

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, bxslider

when i try to use custom pager for bx slider default pager in the top was not displayed. Can any one help me out to display both the pager option in bxslider

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: $('#sliderRight').bxSlider({
   infiniteLoop: true,
   touchEnabled:true,
   oneToOneTouch:true,
   preventDefaultSwipeX:true,
   minSlides:1,
   maxSlides:1,
   moveSlides:1,
   slideWidth:0,
   controls:false,
  pager: true,
  pagerCustom: "#pager"
 });

Comment: What does you #pager contain? Post your HTML code snippet too.

Answer (score -1):

In my code I have used the default pager and have designed the thumbnails with the help of `JQuery`, which is named as `bubble-wrapper class` and each **li** has custom attribute **data-bubble** and contains particular image.

Thumbnails will include the images and on clicking the image and slider will show that image.

To achieve this I used `slider.goToSlide(slideNumber,"direction");`

Direction could be "**prev**"/"**next**" and to determine *slideNumber* I used `data-bubble`.

```
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="bubble" data-bubble="0"><img src="images/photography.png" height="50" title="photography"/></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="bubble" data-bubble="1"><img src="images/photography.png" height="50" title="photography"/></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="bubble" data-bubble="2"><img src="images/photography.png" height="50" title="photography"/></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="bubble" data-bubble="3"><img src="images/photography.png" height="50" title="photography"/></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
$('a.bubble').click(function () {
    var bubbledSlide=$(this).attr("data-bubble");
    console.log("bubbledSlide"+bubbledSlide);
    slider.goToSlide(bubbledSlide,'prev');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just wanted to point out that you didn't really explain your answer at first, it was just some code. And now you added some explanation, so the OP can check it out.